# Stopping and starting startInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this application where I press start button and then the button is changed into a stop button. Start button will start and refresh a counter and stop button will stop it.

Here is the code:

```
var sec = 0;
        var seconds = 0;
        var hundreths = 0;

        function timer(x){
            return x > 9 ? x : "0" + x;
        }

        intervalID = setInterval(function(){
                seconds = timer(parseInt(sec/60, 10));
                hundreths = timer(++sec%60);
                $("#time-id").val("Sekundid: "+seconds+" Sajandikud: "+hundreths);
        }, 10);

        function startTimer(check){
            sec = 0;

        }

        function start(){
            changeButton("start");
            startTimer(true);
        }

        function stop(){
            changeButton("stop");
            startTimer(false);
            clearInterval(intervalID);
        }

        function changeButton(variable){
            if(variable === "start"){
                var div = document.getElementById("game");
                var btn2 = document.createElement("input"); btn2.id = "Stop"; btn2.type = "button"; btn2.value = "Stop";
                clearBox("Start");
                div.appendChild(btn2);
                btn2.onclick = function(){stop()};
            }else if(variable === "stop"){
                var div = document.getElementById("game");
                var btn1 = document.createElement("input"); btn1.id = "Start"; btn1.type = "button"; btn1.value = "Start";
                clearBox("Stop");
                div.appendChild(btn1);
                btn1.onclick = function(){start()};
            }
        }

        window.onload = function (){
            var div = document.getElementById("game");
            var btn1 = document.createElement("input"); btn1.id = "Start"; btn1.type = "button"; btn1.value = "Start";
            div.appendChild(btn1);
            btn1.onclick = function (){start()};
        };

        function clearBox(elementID){
            document.getElementById(elementID).remove();
        }
        <!-- Element removal code -->
        Element.prototype.remove = function() {
            this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
        }

        NodeList.prototype.remove = HTMLCollection.prototype.remove = function() {
            for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++) {
                if(this[i] && this[i].parentElement) {
                    this[i].parentElement.removeChild(this[i]);
                }
            }
        }
```

So the problem here is that I have no idea how I could make the counter to start only when I press the button. Cause right now it will start when page is loaded. Because of scoping, it is difficult to put the setInterval into a seperate function too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

HTML :

```
<button onclick='startInterval()'>Start</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var intervalID;
function startInterval() {
    intervalID = setInterval(function(){
            seconds = timer(parseInt(sec/60, 10));
            hundreths = timer(++sec%60);
            $("#time-id").val("Sekundid: "+seconds+" Sajandikud: "+hundreths);
    }, 10);
}
```